# Erro de compilação: O nome 'x' não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer esse exercício em C#, mas toda vez que eu tento compilar ele aponta o erro:

> O nome i não existe no contexto atual

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

```
int N, a, b;

N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = a; i <= b; i++);
{
    if(i % N == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que tirar o ponto-e-vírgula depois do `for`

```
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++); // <<-- Isso tá errado
```

Precisa ser assim:

```
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
    if(i % N == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, valeu LINQ!

Comment: @AdrianoSanches Não sei se você já sabe como funciona o site, mas sempre que você fizer uma pergunta pode marcar uma resposta como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo da resposta